# Trying to make a wave table oscillator

Tags: c, signal-processing

I am trying to make a wavetable oscillator for an audio project I am working on, but for some reason I just can't seem to get it right. This is my admittedly naive implementation.

```
void BuildTable()
{
    table = (float*)malloc(tableSize * sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
    {
        table[i] = sin((i * 2 * PI * frequency) / samplerate);
    }
 }

 void Process(float* buffer, int count, float frequency, int elapsedSamples)
 {
     float increment = tableSize * (frequency / samplerate);
     float position = fmodf(elapsedSamples * increment, tableSize);
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
        float sample = table[(int)floorf(position)];
        buffer[i] = sample;
        position += increment;
        if (position > tableSize) position -= tableSize;
     }    
  }
```

The output of this is nonsensical buzzes and noise.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for smoother operation and to greatly reduce stack size flucations replace       float sample = table[(int)floorf(position)];
        buffer[i] = sample; with buffer[i] = table[floor(position)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be with `BuildTable`.
One would typically initialize the table with a full sine wave cycle as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
{
    table[i] = sin(i * 2 * PI / tableSize);
}
```

rather than with a specific frequency and sample rate.

Comment: Since sin over a full cycle goes from 0 to 1 to 0 to -1 to 0,  I think the method of creating the table array needs some work.  perhaps using sin( i * const(360/tablesize) ) in generating sin values for the table entries.

Comment: This was it. The wave needs to fill one full cycle in the table. The frequency chosen is supposed to fit perfectly in the table.